# Specific object property values using lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I have an object :

```
{
    "x" : "a",
    "y" : "b",    
    "z" : "c",    
}
```

I have an array : `['x', 'y']`. How do I get an result from the object above as :

```
{
    "x" : "a",
    "y" : "b"
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick)

```js
var data = {
    "x" : "a",
    "y" : "b",    
    "z" : "c",    
};

console.log(_.pick(data, ['x', 'y']));
console.log(_.pick(data, 'x', 'y'));
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.0.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```